# Merge column labels with Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to work with data in a pandas dataframe which I am importing from an [Excel spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18QEGfsgzrmCohUs0oZSck0bdr9uj-Crn00iMFSMC7Zk/edit?usp=sharing).

I am importing the data so it has a multi-index structure.

```
blid_df = pd.read_excel('OriginalClean.xlsx', header=[0,1,2], index_col=None)
```

This produces this dataframe.
[image: dataframe]

I want to index by `Country` which I am able to do using `set_index` however all my countries become tuples (e.g `Australia,`).

I also want to make the country type sit at the correct level and remove these unnamed level labels.

Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Please post the data as [text/code instead of image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also mention what you tried

Comment: You could rename all the columns after you load the data. Having columns with the same name, will not make it happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong but I imagine/suppose that you're reading a multi-header spreadsheet this way :

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=[0, 1, 2])
```

You can try this instead :

```
df = (
    pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=[0, 1], header=[0, 1, 2]) # 1st chain
        .rename_axis(index=["Country", "Country Type"], columns=[None]*3)
)

df.index.nlevels   # should be 2 (previously 1)
df.columns.nlevels # should be 3
```

If you're not dealing with an Excel file, replace the first chain with `df.set_index(list(df.columns[:2]))`.

Comment: Thank you so much this was giving me issues for hours

Answer (score 0):

You could rename all the columns after you load the data. Having columns with the same name, will not make it happy.
Try something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

#proper non repeated column names
column_names = ["new_column_name1", "new_column_name2", "new_column_name3"]
data = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv", names=column_names, header=None)

#proper data_types
data_types = {
    "new_column_name1": str,   # Example: Integer data type
    "new_column_name2": float, # Example: Float data type
    "new_column_name3": int, # Example: Float data type
}

# Set data types
data = data.astype(data_types)

# Use the first column as the index
data = data.set_index("new_column_name1") 

# Reindex the DataFrame
data = data.reindex(drop=True)
```